# How to implement a BFS search ~ java

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

Here is my code:

```
private void doBfs(HiRiQ node, ArrayList<HiRiQ> queue, ArrayList<HiRiQ> path, ArrayList<HiRiQ> visited) {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        HiRiQ current = queue.remove(0);
        if(current.IsSolved()){
            current.print();
            System.out.println("Path found !");
            return;
        } else {    
            if(current.getAllNextStates().isEmpty()){
                return; 
            } else {
                queue.addAll(current.getAllNextStates());
            }
        }
        visited.add(current); 
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to continue with this method. I know that without access to the other methods it should be complicated, but I just want to know what is missing in this bfs-search algorithm.

The goal of this bfs search should be to find if it is possible to find the solved configuration starting from "node".

Note: HiRiQ represents a configuration of a puzzle board (in this case the game is the pegg-solitaire puzzle) and the method getAllNextStates() generates all the different board configurations that are one move away from the current one.

When I run it it just doesn't find any solution, it runs interminably.

Comment: What is *specifically* wrong with the current code? Are you receiving some kind of error? If so, what does it say? Is the algorithm not performing as expected? If so, what is it doing and how should it behave differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an idea of breadth-first (cause I feel you are unclear on it), for let's say a simple binary tree, and that should make it clearer for you.

Say this is our tree.

```
           1
     /           \
    2             3
  /   \         /   \
4      5       6     7
```

Now, take since we need to do a breadth-first search, lets look at a queue data structure.

```
queue -> []
```

Lets put a reference to our root in the `queue`

```
queue -> [1]
```

while `queue` is not empty...

```
- pop the first element, i.e. 1
- if it has a left child, add it to the queue [2]
- if it has a right child, add it to the queue [2,3]
- repeat
```

How will this work?

```
pop first element, i.e. 1; queue -> []
- if it has a left child, add it to the queue [2]
- if it has a right child, add it to the queue [2,3]

pop first element, i.e. 2; queue -> [3]
- if it has a left child, add it to the queue [3,4]
- if it has a right child, add it to the queue [3,4,5]

pop first element, i.e. 3; queue -> [4,5]
- if it has a left child, add it to the queue [4,5,6]
- if it has a right child, add it to the queue [4,5,6,7]

pop first element, i.e. 4; queue -> [5,6,7]
- if it has a left child, add it to the queue [5,6,7]
- if it has a right child, add it to the queue [5,6,7]

pop first element, i.e. 5; queue -> [6,7]
- if it has a left child, add it to the queue [6,7]
- if it has a right child, add it to the queue [6,7]

pop first element, i.e. 6; queue -> [7]
- if it has a left child, add it to the queue [7]
- if it has a right child, add it to the queue [7]

pop first element, i.e. 7; queue -> []
- if it has a left child, add it to the queue []
- if it has a right child, add it to the queue []

queue is empty
```

I hope this will clear your understanding and help you with your problem.

Comment: Thank you this clears up a lot ! So in my case, how would it be possible that it seems to run indefinitely ?

Comment: A potential problem could be because of `queue.addAll(current.getAllNextStates());`; an obvious **issue** is that you would need to ensure that the `current` is not already in `visited`, if it is, simply `continue` to the next iteration; these are 2 potential problems.

Comment: It can get extremely complex trying to solve this entire issue over here without more code. But, based on what I have said, it should work out.

Comment: How could I limit the actual size of queue ?

Comment: Well, you could keep track of the `queue.size()`. Again, it depends on what you end goal is. Ideally in a BFS, we continue till the `queue` is empty, hoping that we would have found our solution somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 0):

As @DebosmitRay points out, the issue is probably that you don't check that a node has already been visited. So your search likely gets stuck in an infinite loop.

To help you along, here is a rough framework for implementing a BFS in Java. You'll have to implement the game/domain-specific logic yourself, e.g. configuration of the pieces, the test for whether or not a player has won. This can be implement inside a `State` object:

```
interface State{
    public List<State> getNeighbors();
    public boolean isGoal();
}
```

A BFS searches through states that are linked to their parent states. This linkage can be handled by a `Node` class similar to the following:

```
class Node {

    private final State state;
    private final Node parent;

    Node(State state, Node parent){
        this.state = state;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node getParent(){return this.parent;}

    /** 
     * @return a List of neighbor Nodes that can be reached in a single move
     */
    public List<Node> getNeighbors(){
        List<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for(State state : state.getNeighbors()){
            neighbors.add(new Node(state,this));
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(!(o instanceof Node)) return false;
        Node other = (Node) o;
        return state.equals(other.state); 
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return state.hashCode();
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString(){
        return "Node containing: " + state.toString();
    }

}
```

The BFS logic is then simple to implement:

```
private void doBfs(State start) {

    List<Node> openList = new  ArrayList<>();
    Set<Node> closedSet = new HashSet<>();

    Node startNode = new Node(start,null);
    openList.add(startNode);

    while (!openList.isEmpty()) {

        Node current = openList.remove(0);

        //If this node has already been visited, skip it
        if(closedSet.contains(current)) continue;


        //check if the current node is a goal (solution) node
        if (current.isGoal()) {

            System.out.println("Path found !");

            //print the path by iterating over the parents
            for(Node parent = current; parent != null; parent = parent.getParent()){
                System.out.println(parent);
            }

            return;
        }

        //Add all neighbors to the openList
        openList.addAll(current.getNeighbors());

        //Add the current node to the closed set so that it is not revisted
        closedSet.add(current);
    }

    System.out.println("No solution could be found from the starting state "+ start);

}
```